# How to set line height if the word exceeded width

Tags: html, css

I am using unorder list like below. I want to change line-height if line breaks or the word wrap.

```
   .vj
{
    width:200px;
}
<div class="vj" style="line-height:32px;">
    <ul>
        <li>Neil Armstrong defines an unordered</li>
        <li>Alan Bean</li>
        <li>Peter Conrad</li>
        <li>Edgar Mitchell</li>
        <li>Alan Shepard</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Expexted OutPut:**

**Set line-height 22px instead of 32px if line break that li only.**

[image]

Code : https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GRKFA6EKC3XM

How to know the 'li' is exceeded the width?

How to set Line height to the exceeded 'li'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
lis.forEach((e)=>{
  if(e.offsetHeight != 32){
    e.style.lineHeight = "22px";
  }
})
```

```css
.vj {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vj" style="line-height:32px;">
  <ul>
    <li>Neil Armstrong defines an unordered</li>
    <li>Alan Bean</li>
    <li>Peter Conrad</li>
    <li>Edgar Mitchell</li>
    <li>Alan Shepard</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

set line-height in li item or ul item with your need
like this

```css
   .vj
{
    width:200px;
}
#line{line-height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="vj" style="line-height:32px;">
    <ul>
        <li id="line">Neil Armstrong defines an unordered</li>
        <li>Alan Bean</li>
        <li>Peter Conrad</li>
        <li>Edgar Mitchell</li>
        <li>Alan Shepard</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution

```css
.vj{width:200px;}
.vj ul li{line-height:18px; margin-bottom:8px}
```

```html
   
<div class="vj" style="line-height:32px;">
    <ul>
        <li>Neil Armstrong defines an unordered</li>
        <li>Alan Bean</li>
        <li>Peter Conrad</li>
        <li>Edgar Mitchell</li>
        <li>Alan Shepard</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]